# oracle 11r2 don't work trigger on delete, update, insert

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have two tables  and one trigger. I need update one table before insert or update or delete other table. I write trigger, but is doesn't working.
There kod of trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TT.BF_SHT_BAZ2   
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON KADR.BAZ2
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  IF inserting
  THEN
    UPDATE DAT20 d20
      SET d20.DINP = d20.DINP + 1
      WHERE d20.PODR = :NEW.KOD
      AND d20.SLUG = :NEW.SLU
      AND d20.DOLG = :NEW.DOL;


  ELSIF updating
  THEN

    UPDATE DAT20 d20
      SET d20.DINP = d20.DINP - 1
      WHERE d20.PODR = :OLD.KOD
      AND d20.SLUG = :OLD.SLU
      AND d20.DOLG = :OLD.DOL;

    UPDATE DAT20 d20
      SET d20.DINP = d20.DINP + 1
      WHERE d20.PODR = :NEW.KOD
      AND d20.SLUG = :NEW.SLU
      AND d20.DOLG = :NEW.DOL;


  ELSIF deleting
  THEN
    UPDATE DAT20 d20
      SET d20.DINP = d20.DINP - 1
      WHERE d20.PODR = :NEW.KOD
      AND d20.SLUG = :NEW.SLU
      AND d20.DOLG = :NEW.DOL;

  ELSE
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Err redact d20.DINP ');
  END IF;

END;
```

Comment: sorry for the bad design

Comment: thank http://stackoverflow.com/users/2568341/kordirko for good design

Comment: When you say "not working", do you mean that DAT20.DINP remains unchanged after a successful operation on BAZ2, or that some error occurs?

Comment: Trying maintain a running total on another table via a trigger is likely to run into problems when you have multiple users; simultaneous changes may end up with an incorrect total. You may be better off counting the records on at the point you need the total.on BAZ2.

Comment: You seem to have at least two schemas; the trigger is being created in TT, the table it's against is in KADR. Which schema is DAT20 in?

Comment: I make update , delete and insert in baz2, (from php and desctop programs) but d20.Dinp not change. Schema tt this is my mistacke when i write this post. One schema is kadr. Php connect to oracle via one user and all  do (select, update and other)

Comment: Add some sample data for both tables to the question, and the insert/update you're doing. We don't know if what you're showing is right; does PODR  really match KOD? Are any of the old or new values you're comparing or updating null? Have you done any debugging (e.g. with dbms_output calls to see what's happening)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is so simple that I am ashamed. My DAT20.DINP was NULL, and NULL + 1 = NULL. I set DAT20.DINP to 0 and all working!